# How to restart an onclicklistener after switching layouts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, onclicklistener

I just started coding in AndroidStudio and Java so I don't have a great grasp yet. Basically, when I click the withdrawBtn I have it switch to a different layout, then when I click it should switch back to the activity_main layout. The problem is once I am back in the activity_main layout, clicking the withdrawBtn no longer does anything. How can I fix this so it works once I've returned to the main layout.

```
withdrawBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_window);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);
    rlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is probably because you are creating new layout without click listener. I will suggest that you will refrain from doing that. Rather, just create a your Relative Layout and set the visibility to GONE. Then when you click on the button and you can set the visibility to VISIBLE. That way you will avoid creating new layouts everytime

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the withdrawBtn isn't working anymore is because you're re-inflating the layout upon a button press.

What is currently happening is:

1. In the original Activity, you've inflated the `R.layout.activity_main` and set `withdrawBtn.setOnClickListener()` after that layout has been inflated.
2. You inflate `R.layout.popup_window` and this actually replaces everything from the previous layout with the new layout.
3. You set `rlayout.setOnTouchListener()` and have it switch to the previous layout.

However, keep in mind that what's happening is that you're replacing old layouts with new layouts... so all the `setOnClickListeners` and `setOnTouchListeners` are actually gone. This is why your **withdrawBtn** doesn't work anymore. It's because it doesn't have an onClickListener anymore. To fix this, you simply have to add an onClickListener to it.

**HOWEVER, although that is the solution to your question, I MUST point out that your way of navigating through your app is a HUGE problem.**

**DO NOT CONTINUE WITH WHAT YOU ARE DOING.**

The way you're inflating layouts upon a button press is not how Android is meant to open new screens. By constantly inflating a new layout, you're essentially disregarding all previous code meant for that layout... which can easily cause crashes to occur due to code referencing Views that don't exist anymore.

In a way, you're making your code messier just to achieve a result that gives you inefficient and potentially buggy results.

For Android, there's actually two commonly used solutions for navigating to new screens:

1. **Start a new Activity** - You're allowed to create multiple Activities in your app. Every Activity should inflate exactly one layout. If you have a MainActivity and a PopUpWindowActivity, you can simply use `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindowActivity.class));` to open the new PopupWindow Activity. When you're done in PopupWindowActivity, you can simply call `finish();` to close that Activity and return to MainActivity. Optionally, you can use `startActivity()` too to return to MainActivity if you don't wish to close PopUpWindowActivity. Here's more info about this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java
2. **Use a single Activity with multiple Fragments** -  Similarly, each Activity and Fragments should inflate only one layout. However, the whole concept around Fragments is too much to explain in simple words, so read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Avoid using `setContentView()` more than once per Activity and only do it if there's no other choice... which I can safely say with 100% confidence that there is always a better option.